# How do I manually throttle the CPU usage of an app?

Tags: memory, performance, imovie

When I export a file from iMovie, it usually takes a long time but uses a lot of CPU, and my computer gets very hot(around 180-190ºF), even with my fan controller maxing it out. Would I be able to slow this down so that it wouldn't put as much load on my computer? Or really for any app where it might be doing some intensive thing in the background. I get a little nervous having it working so hard for such a long period of time. I was hoping there would be some terminal command or other local way to do this,  Thanks.

A1342 MacBook, Late 2009, 10.10.5, 4GB RAM

Comment: This is what the Macbook is designed to do what is the issue here

Comment: Yes but I'd prefer to slow it down more than what it automatically does, I'm not comfortable with it getting so hot.

Comment: Don't worry about it getting hot. It won't get damaged. The PC is designed if it gets too hot it'll shut down before any damage. Let the PC do the job at it's max capacity otherwise you'll complain that it's not doing the best it can, is to slow... To add to @mspasov's answer, I have tried the app, wouldn't recommend it. You'll notice that it slows down your workflow significantly. Mac's are designed to be very efficient, embrace it, otherwise you could've gone with another PC.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [AppTamer](http://www.stclairsoft.com/AppTamer/index.html) (not free, trial version available). From the AppTamer website:

> Some applications, particularly web browsers and older apps, continue 
>   running tasks or animating ads even when they're idle. That uses
>   valuable processing (CPU) power, which leaves you with:
>
> Less CPU power for the application you're using, Increased heat and fan
>   noise, Reduced battery run-time
>
> Find the culprits and get them under control. With App Tamer, you
>   simply do this:
>
> Launch App Tamer and click on its icon in your    menubar, Click on an
>   application that's    using a lot of CPU, Tell App Tamer to slow or stop
>   the app.

Comment: Yes this is great! Thank you! And I'll probably only be needing it for a little while, so just a trial's probably ok, thanks!